# Php fopen create random int

Tags: php, random, int

right now I am struggling to right a new file to a server by using the fopen. I can use the fopen but it needs to be like this:

```
$myfile = fopen("newfile.html", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

I want instead of "newfile.html" to write a random file name with random integers. Is this possible? Let me know.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php <- just be aware of the note

Comment: `$myfile = fopen(rand(1,100).'.html', "w");`

Comment: If you want a unique filename you could use [tempnam()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php)

Comment: @user3312132 Just to say it, this won't create a file every time, since the number is maybe 23 twice

Answer (score 0):

try using the `rand()` function. [PHP RAND()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)